# Draw border around cells in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` this is an example:

[image]

I want to draw a rectangle around yellow color, I have the cells indexes, can someone help me?

I will be very grateful

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: There's a method called AdjustCellBorderStyle() in the DataGridViewCell class. Give it a look, it may help you

Comment: somthing is not clear for me, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you do is set the Cell's Style.BackColor property:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 3
  dgv.Rows(2).Cells(i).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
Next
```

One way to get a rectangle around the cells is to use the CellPainting event and see if it's yellow or not, then test the neighboring cells to determine whether or not to draw a border line:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellPainting(sender As Object, _
                             e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) _
                             Handles dgv.CellPainting

  If (e.CellStyle.BackColor.ToArgb = Color.Yellow.ToArgb) Then
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, e.CellBounds)
    If (e.ColumnIndex = 0 OrElse _
      dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex - 1).Style.BackColor.ToArgb <> Color.Yellow.ToArgb) Then
      e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, _
                          e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom)
    End If
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, _
                        e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Top)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, _
                        e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1)
    If (e.ColumnIndex = dgv.Rows.Count - 1 OrElse _
      dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1).Style.BackColor.ToArgb <> Color.Yellow.ToArgb) Then
      e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, _
                          e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom)
    End If
    e.Handled = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for help,but I do this, i need to draw a rectagle, to draw a  line, or a border solid around yellow color